# What's the difference between using SPICE and just putting things on breadboard and testing?

Tags: breadboard, spice, prototyping, development

Can SPICE programs do most of the imaginable simulations with any kind of components in the market? Is it important to run SPICE before you do any kind of breadboard work/prototyping?

Answer (score 6):

SPICE is a design tool. Before SPICE, some circuits (maybe certain types of analogue filter for example) needed laborious calculations to get anywhere near the right values and then, after protoyping you'd probably adjust a few values because those laborious calculations were virtually impossible to get right (or needed several/plenty tedious iterations).

SPICE, as I use it, probably saves me, on average 1 iteration of circuit board on the  designs that I do.

I still scheme up what I think is correct. I then use spice to tweak values and probably add a few bits and pieces of circuit because I hadn't adequately considered this or that. I try not to use spice as a pre-requisite for good thinking although now and then I've started with no real thoughts on how to crack a problem and just developed something in parts and linked them together. Probably not the best way to do things but sometimes it works.

I always run spice before building anything and I can vouch for it saving my company a shed load of money each year. I probably design 20 PCBs per annum and saving one iteration per design makes it totally cost effective both in external artwork costs and the labour cost of building that extra (now not required) PCB iteration.

On the face of it spice can't do everything but as you progress, you learn how to import models, create models and apply work-arounds for weaknesses. I would not be without it.

Comment: What SPICE tool do you use ?

Comment: @efox29 I use micro-cap. Do you use one or are you in the market. LTSpice is supposed to be good and free?

Comment: I was just asking. I use LTSPICE when I need something quick. I've had a trial of MC9 or 10 sometime back and ya it was good.

Answer (score 3):

SPICE is a simulation. Components on a breadboard are rather real (unless everything is just part of a simulation, but that's [a topic of Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/551/23)).

While you can incorporate things like tolerance deviations, noise, and other artifacts in a simulation, there's no guarantee that you didn't miss something or that the simulator will be 100% accurate.

Running a simulation first can be extremely helpful though, to know roughly if something will work within your specifications before you purchase parts, or worse, damage or destroy them accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a simple question...

The one of the main advantages of using simulators is that it make the prototyping work really fast and cheap. There is no need to solder, to buy components, to think how to put them on the breadboard. If something goes wrong, you can change the schematic and run another simulation in seconds.

But there are disadvantages as well - at first, the simulator is not a real circuit. It is a model - you can get weird results if the model is not properly created. And you have to distinguish "realistic" results from "not realistic" - sometimes it is not easy task.

Additional problems can arise, if the schematic contains exotic parts that are not handled by the standard libraries. In this case you have to make your own models and it is not easy task as well. (As an example - there is still no good models of electrical discharge in gases - for example automotive spark plug. The theory is not very clear.)

Anyway, the conclusion: modeling can save a lot of work and can accelerate the development, but it have to be made reasonable, with knowledge and understanding.